# Low cost way to check whether Archetypes File has payload (BLOB)

Tags: blob, plone, archetypes

Is there a way to quick check whether Archetypes File field contains payload or not, without actually loading the content of the file to memory?

I am remotely syncing files into Archetypes content items and I'd like to avoid the sync iteration if the file already exists. I am potentially iterating through hundreds of files, so I'd like to avoid the situation Plone reads every file to memory just whether is has zero bytes or some other data.

Plone 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

On ATFiles there's a size() method to check the file size. It seems that the size isn't stored anywhere, so maybe a adding a column on the catalog will work for you.

Comment: Do you mean that calling size() will read the blob and call its len()?

Comment: I believe you can do a field level `get_size` check - look at `plone.app.blob.field`

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa it has to know the size from somewhere, be calling its lenght, or, if you are using blobs, querying the filesystem. If the size() is cached somewhere and thus the size is not checked everytime, you should investigate where is stored, if not, just add a column on portal_catalog and that way you can also query for them.

Comment: Mikko maybe you are interested in: http://dev.plone.org/ticket/12041. So far it seems that it checks at runtime.